# How to set alternatives in 10.8?

Tags: command-line, macos

On Linux you can use `update-alternative` to change the version of a command.

Which command in OS X (10.8) will switch the alternative of the current command?

Comment: There's no such thing on OS X. What command are you talking about? What problem are you facing or why are you asking? Knowing this would give you a better answer.

Comment: @slhck One reason one might want this is for the ability to use multiple versions of java, if working on multiple projects that require different versions.

Comment: Switching between Java Versions on MacOS you can use `jenv` (`brew install jenv`) – check this [site](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/change-java-version-mac/#:~:text=First,%20we%20need%20to%20change,libexec%20using%20the%20cd%20command.&text=Once%20we%20are%20in%20the,locations%20of%20the%20installed%20Java.&text=Here%20is%20the%20output%20after%20running%20the%20command.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I understand the motivation behind your question. `update-alternatives` elegantly solves the problem of managing several installed versions of a program (for example Java) or different ports of a program (`vim` vs. `elvis` vs. `vile`) by making one of them the default one.

`update-alternatives`, found in many Linux distros, creates and manages a set of symlinks from `/bin`, `/usr/bin` (and the like) to `/etc/alternatives`, and from there to the location where the program is installed.

For example, in [openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/) `java` is symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/java`, which is symlinked to a "private" path where `java` resides:

```
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0/jre/bin/java
```

Unfortunately, and although [some](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2008-May/005172.html) think it would be necessary, at least for MacPorts, **there is no such thing in OS X**. I have personally solved the lack of `update-alternatives` with aliases in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='/usr/local/bin/ls'
```

or simply changing `$PATH`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

If you can't solve it like this and are weighing the fact of porting it to OS X be aware that although `update-alternatives`' first incarnation was a Perl script, it was [rewritten in C](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/05/27/rewriting-update-alternatives-in-c/) for Debian, and some other distros adopted it later (for instance openSUSE 12.1).

openSUSE 11.4 provides the Perl version as an [RPM package](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.4/standard/noarch/update-alternatives-1.14.19-30.33.1.noarch.rpm). If you are looking for the C version, go for any recent Ubuntu or Debian release, or openSUSE 12.1 or later.

Comment: `update-alternatives` is very specifically a Debian thing, I believe (though obviously many other distros are based on Debian; but you won't find it on many RPM-based distros, Gentoo, etc).

Comment: @tripleee You have things like `alternative` on other Linux distr

Answer (score 1):

Macports supports this capability via 'port select' for many language packages, mysql, and others.  (I'm using version MacPorts 2.4.2.)